# Which account is "Downloading Messages" in Mail.app?

Tags: email, macos

Mail.app has an "Activity" floating window. That window has a list of tasks being performed. One typical task is "Downloading Messages". How can I tell **which account this task relates to**? I have an iCloud account, a Google account, a POBox.com account, and more.

Comment: Bumping this question -- I would also like to know how to tell which account is doing the "Downloading Messages" (or "Checking for new mail" or "Moving messages" or any number of other activities that Mail does).